# Как сделать круглую картинку с фоном с помощью CSS, SVG?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, position

У меня не получается правильно расположить картинку в родительском элементе – даже несмотря на то, что картинке заданы правильные отступы от краев родительского элемента, она продолжает вылезать.

Может быть я вообще выбираю неправильный способ реализации?
Вот мой код:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent_block {
  margin: 30px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  width: 195px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 16px;
 right: 8px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 184px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_block">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png" alt="photo">
</div>
```

Мне надо сделать вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно просто точно позиционировать, не забывая про `overflow: hidden` для контейнера:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent_block {
  position: relative;
  height: 195px;
  width: 195px;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 23px;
  height: 184px;
  width: 163px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_block">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png" alt="photo">
</div>
```

Если картинка не подгружается и является статичной, то можно избавиться и от тега `<img>`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  height: 195px;
  width: 195px;
  margin: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: url('https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png');
  background-position: 23px bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
}
.avatar:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -36px 3px 83px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

На будущее: не обрезайте изображения заранее, если они должны иметь примитивные формы - это, во-первых, избавит от лишней работы в графическом редакторе (а подрезать можно средствами CSS). Во-вторых, проще будет позиционировать, ибо лишнее обрежется контейнером, но не будет этой борьбы с просветами.

Comment: Добавь ещё: дзинь-дзинь или тук-тук аудио сэмпл и будет полная картина дверного глазка :) при наведении

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: а вдруг кто-то запустит, а у него ребёнок только уснул? Да и JS нужно добавлять тогда, а это оффтоп.

Comment: ну это была шутка, а не предложение

Comment: "Если картинка не подгружается и является статичной, то..." в каком смысле картинка является статичной? Они же вроде как всё не двигаются на странице, если без анимации и переходов, конечно)))

Comment: @Eva: в данном случае, я подразумеваю, что адрес картинки задаётся сразу и не меняется в дальнейшем. На самом деле, это не проблема, но `src` у `<img>` проще поменять, чем `background-image: url()`, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 4):

### Решение SVG pattern

Решение достаточно простое и универсальное.
Надеюсь, комментарии в коде помогут разобраться с основными моментами

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png"  width="100%" height="100%" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
      <!-- Фон -->
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"  fill="#EEEEEE" />
    <!-- Изображение помещенное в круг с помощью паттерна -->
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"  fill="url(#img)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Решение CSS

```css
.container {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
img {
background:#eee;
width:200px;
height:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

```html
<div class-"container">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png" />
</div>
```

Вращение при наведении

```css
.container {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
img {
background:#eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QMsSJWR6/Photo.png" />
</div>
```